# C permission denied for queue creation

Tags: c, message-queue, permission-denied

I'm trying to create a queue, but I'm getting a permission denied error. I got this error before, but then I added code for error catching on the key creation and it was working. The only thing I've changed since then is I put my queue creation code in a separate function. Here's something like what my code looks like:

```
key_t key1;
int msqid1;

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
        getKeys();            
        queueCreate();         
}

void getKeys()                  
{
        if ((key1 = ftok(".", '1')) == -1)  
        {
                perror("key1 creation");
                exit(1);
        }
}

void queueCreate()
{
        if ((msqid1 = msgget(key1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        {
                perror("msqid1 creation");
                exit(1);
        }
}
```

The error thrown is "msqid1 creation: Permission denied". Any ideas?

Comment: Are `key1` and `msqid1` global?

Comment: Yes, they're declared outside of main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you didn't destroy the message queue on the one occasion it was successfully created, so now you can't recreate it because it still exists.

You don't indicate which platform you're on.  Classically, you'd use the `ipcs` command to obtain the status of the various IPC systems (shared memory, semaphores, and message queues), and `ipcrm` to remove IPC systems that are no longer wanted.

Comment: I'm SSHing into a linux server. I tried this after a day or 2 of not running my code, but ipcs lists no queues under my user name.

Comment: @Nick: maybe that's the trouble - the queue ID (key) is already in use by another user (so you can't create it again).  Have you looked at the key ID you get back?  Your code seems to work OK on both MacOS X and Linux for me - leaving a message queue around.

Comment: Well, the odd thing is it worked before. But there's been a user created queue listed under ipcs that's been up for a few days so maybe coincidentally we're using the same key ID.
EDIT: I changed the int ID from '1' to 'q' and now it works. Apparently whoever forgot to delete their queue just happened to have the same key >: |

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be `EACCES` and not `EEXIST`. My linux man page says:

> EACCES A message queue exists for key, but the calling process does
>   not have permission to access the queue, and does not have the
>   CAP_IPC_OWNER capability.

Did you check for these conditions?

You are using the current directory as a path for `ftok`. Maybe change to a plain local file in "/tmp" and not in your home folder (nfs?).

Comment: I know someone else doing the same project that used the current folder as the directory, but I'll try playing around with it.